# How do I handle static data in sinatra/ruby apps?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra application that needs some static data (~15'000 key/value-pairs). The data does only change every few months or so. I do not want to store the data in a database (the app does not use any other data storage and I dont't want to add any just because of this).

I currently have the following solution:

`data/invTypes.yml`:

```
18: "Plagioclase"
19: "Spodumain"
20: "Kernite"
21: "Hedbergite"
22: "Arkonor"
25: "Corpse"
34: "Tritanium"
35: "Pyerite"
36: "Mexallon"
37: "Isogen"
```

And then in my `app.rb` I do something like this:

```
# load Type IDS from Static Data
IDS = YAML.load(open('data/invTypes.yml').read
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: "is there a better solution" - What don't you like about this one?

Comment: I worry about my memory footprint once the dataset gets bigger or more data is added.

Comment: The way to combat memory bloat is to not load stuff you don't need (now). How is this applicable to your app - I have no way to know (except you telling me all about it)

Comment: For example: If some items are used much more frequently than others, put them in a separate file. So that you won't need to load all the "cold" keys when you need only one of the "hot" ones.

Comment: 15000 k/v pairs? This is, like, 100kb of data. If your machine is so underpowered that you have to count kilobytes, you have chosen a wrong technology for the app, my friend. :)

Comment: It does'nt seem like much but the dataset ist potentionally much much larger ;-)

Comment: *Potentially* you'll be using a database :)

Comment: On a larger dataset you’ll be interested in quick data access based on queries. SQL is proven to be a winner in this area. That said, the very first problem you’ll meet on potentially huge dataset is _not_ a memory consumption, is a _data access time_.

Comment: You can try doing a JSON file. Regardless, this should work properly as well. I guess it depends on how much overhead you get from reading the file. You could even do a CSV file and just split on commas. There are many ways to do this, it just depends on your needs. YAML should work just fine though. Also, seems that you are playing eve-online?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting this data in RAM (since it's fast, and you have enough of it), the only thing I would optimize is to make sure that you parse the file only if necessary and not on every request. Maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525482/in-sinatraruby-how-should-i-create-global-variables-which-are-assigned-values