# Use PORT environment variable in Rack/Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, port, rack

I'm looking to set the listening port within my Rack and Sinatra app, using the PORT environment variable if set otherwise to a default.

I thought I may be able to do something like the following but I'm unsure if this is even the right approach.

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  set :port, ENV['PORT'] || 3000

  get '/' do
    'Hello, World!'
  end
end
```

This doesn't seem to work, at least not with the `rackup` command. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean [how do I set and use global variables in Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525482/in-sinatraruby-how-should-i-create-global-variables-which-are-assigned-values)?

Comment: @tadman I don't, I'm asking how to set the port using an environment variable...

Comment: What about this isn't working? `PORT=9090 rackup`

Comment: @tadman Well it runs on port 9292 when I do that!

Comment: so, there are no issues here?

Comment: @maxpleaner Uhm...well that's the wrong port...

Comment: My experience with Sinatra is that it seems to ignores the port configuration variable set inside the application controller class as far as what `rackup` sees. Even if you wrote, `set :port, 8080` directly, it would still be 9292, so it's not an environment variable reading issue. I ended up always just writing the port I want on the `rackup` command line, as the posted answer indicated. I was not aware of the `config.ru` comment method, which the answer also shows. I may change over to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rackup` takes `-p PORT` argument.

You can do:

```
rackup -p $PORT
```

In `config.ru` you can also define the options in a comment on the first line:

```
#\ -p 9090
```

I'm not sure if that can handle `$PORT`.

If you look at the source code for `rackup`, it's very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rack"
Rack::Server.start
```

That's the whole file.

`Rack::Server.start` accepts an options hash as parameter and one of the options is `:Port`.

You could make your own `start.sh` that says:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rack"
Rack::Server.start(Port: ENV['PORT'] || 3000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer – I didn't know about starting Rack programatically, I think I'll use that!

Comment: `Parsing options from the first comment line is no longer supported` Rack 3.0.9